# Change AppleID to @me.com email address

Tags: apple-id

When I first got an iPod (several years ago) my primary email address was *@gmail.com and, thus, I used that as my AppleID. However, since then Apple has given customers new *@me.com email addresses to use with, say, iPhones and iPads. So, I was wondering what the reprecussions of using *@me.com as my AppleID would be? In other words, would I lose access to movies and TV shows that I've purchased, and would I lose access to my apps?

Answer (score 3):

The key is to change the main Apple ID email address or add an alternate email address instead of creating a new Apple ID altogether.

If you logon to [appleid.apple.com](http://appleid.apple.com), you can *change* your primary email address. There really aren't many big repercussions, and as long as you *don't* create a new Apple ID you will have access to all of your previously purchased content.

If you have friends that iMessage your @gmail.com email address you will need to add that email as an alternate email address - something you can do from  [appleid.apple.com](http://appleid.apple.com).

What is interesting is that you can use your @me.com email address right now to sign into your devices. It is added as an alternate email address automatically. When you log in to [appleid.apple.com](http://appleid.apple.com) you will notice that under your primary email address is an "Alternate Apple ID". This is probably your @me.com or @icloud.com email address. So, you can use that email address and your current Apple ID password to sign in to your Apple ID - either will work.

Note that you can't login to your Apple ID with your "Alternate Email Addresses", but you can iMessage from your "Alternate Email addresses".